# Who should our Moderators Pro Tempore be?

Tags: discussion, moderation

This community needs to start contributing some names they would like to act as provisional Moderators. Please read this: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)**.

Here are some basic guidelines:

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer (not commenting), adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves. Use the `---` to separate it from the nomination.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I'm interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts / social network referrals about the site, etc.

Here is what we are looking for in a Moderator...

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.

Bonus points for:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

---

Please try to use a format similar to the following when posting a nomination under this question:

> ### [Name](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/-1/)
>
> <sup>(liked to profile)</sup>
>
> ### [Meta](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/)
>
> <sup>(linked to meta profile)</sup>
>
> [profile for Community on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/-1.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/-1)
>
> They are active on both the main and meta sites. They were involved in the Scope creation and took lead in closing the Off Topic questions.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Edited in by nominee</sup>
>
> I accept / decline this nomination
>
> I am Name / Age / Fun Fact and I live in XYZ, so should be active on the site from Xpm - Ypm EST (Xpm - Ypm UTC)

Comment: Since we are still a relatively small community, I would encourage self-nominations first. Those who are willing and have the time to manage the site should just step up. I mean, it's no use I nominate, say, Cassidy if he's too busy anyway doing awesome stuff for elementary to be a moderator here :)

Comment: I'd suggest you do nominate someone if you want to. They can always decline, or just not accept

Comment: It should probably be noted that there will be "about three" moderators initially, if this 5 year old post can be taken at face value. ".. the process of identifying and organizing a team of provisional Moderators from within each community (about three per site, starting  about seven days into the public Beta)"

Comment: @LewisGoddard yes, they typically go for 3 and I can't see why they would have more on this site.

Comment: @Tim It also says they generally look for moderators a week after public, and we're still in private beta.

Comment: @LewisGoddard The 3 I've been on have appointed at the transition.

Comment: @Tim You've been a Moderator Pro Tempore before?

Comment: @LewisGoddard No, I meant private betas :) I've participated in 3 (2 succeeded).

Answer (score 12):

### [Lewis Goddard](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/26/lewis-goddard)

#### [Meta](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/users/26/lewis-goddard)

#### [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/45477/lewis-goddard)

[profile for Community on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/904259.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/904259/lewis-goddard)

- elementary web team member
- Very active in the larger community (Google+, Twitter, etc)
- Participates in related sites Ask Ubuntu and Super User
- All around nice guy. Very level headed.
- Has professional editing experience

---

#### I accept this nomination.

My full name is Lewis William Alfred Goddard (which has *so* many possible nicknames), and am studying Computer Science, while working full-time as a Production Technician, and running my own organisation as a Systems Architect. In my spare time I work with the rest of the elementary Web Team, and I use elementary OS as my main OS, although thanks to my various jobs I touch pretty much all the systems.

Comment: I would also like it noted that I have the most badges on the site right now, not that I'm an achievement hunter or anything.

Answer (score 9):

### [Marvin Beckers](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/75/embik)

#### [Meta](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/users/75/embik)

#### [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/137360/embik)

[profile for Community on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/6211794.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/6211794)

- elementary desktop developer
- Very active in the larger community (Google+, Reddit, etc)
- Participates in related sites Ask Ubuntu and Unix & Linux
- Reserves judgement. Good listener. Makes his own opinions.

---

**I accept this nomination!**

A bit late to the party, but I'd be honored to moderate the elementary OS StackExchange - As Dan pointed out, I'm developing (for) the elementary OS desktop and try to engage with the community as often as possible (via G+, via reddit and now via SE). Currently, I'm 19 years old and in an apprenticeship to become an IT engineer, but programming has been my passion for far longer. I'd love to contribute to elementary OS by helping out and moderating on this site :)

Comment: @Tim For sure. I try to play an active role in all our communities :)

Comment: That's great news! Could Cassidy be in as well? (sorry I can't place a nomination myself atm)

By the way, how many mods do we need?

Comment: @saintjules I'm not sure StackExchange are quite asking for moderators just yet (a week into public is the norm), but they want "about 3".

Comment: @LewisGoddard thanks

Comment: I haven't interacted with @embik much so far, but I like what Daniel says about him, and after taking a look at his contributions, they certainly seem to match. I found nothing but clear, informative answers, cordial language, and sensible opinions. LGTM!

Answer (score 9):

### [RolandiXor](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/242/rolandixor)

#### [Meta](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/users/242/rolandixor)

#### [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/29867/)

#### [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/1992/rolandixor)

[profile for Community on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/243378.png](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/242/rolandixor)

- Many high voted questions
- Several good answers
- Colossal Ask Ubuntu reputation score
- Adorable cat gifs

---

*I am RolandiXor, and I approve this message.*

Answer (score 6):

### [Daniel Foré](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/45/daniel-for%C3%A9)

### [Meta](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/users/45/daniel-for%C3%A9)

[profile for Daniel Foré on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/5817568.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/5817568)

Daniel is the founder of this wonderful operating system, and has been active from day 1.

He has a lot to bring to this site from the reasons behind design that no-one else can which will make this community a unique place to be.

He also has a lot of experience of support with elementary. I'm sure he will edit with more info about him if he accepts this nomination.

---

**I accept this nomination!**

I try to maintain an active presence in all our communities and stay active answering questions between here, reddit, twitter, tumblr, google+, etc. Staying in touch with the problems and questions people have is an important part of planning our future development! I also have lots of great inside information ;) I definitely work to champion our [Code of Conduct](https://elementary.io/code-of-conduct) and help make elementary OS available to as many people as I can :)

Comment: I'm ambivalent about Daniel. He unquestionably has the best interests of the community at heart, but the way he communicates isn't always the neutral, welcoming tone I'd like to see from moderators. The fact that he has strong opinions, and that he occupies a very (arguably the most) visible position within the community means that he is the target of much direct criticism and that his posts are more scrutinized, so I understand that less judicious interactions have caught my eye disproportionately—but the fact is that they *do* exist, so I can't endorse him for moderator in good conscience.

Comment: @waldyrious does have a good point - for example the meta requests (imo) have been about keeping elementary what it is now with the branding, which may not fit in with an SE community (feel free to prove me wring :-D). However, I would see him as a good moderator.

Comment: @waldyrious definitely interested in any comments about places where I haven't been neutral and how I can improve those answers.

Comment: I would say the the phrasing "we don't have plans" could be better - it sounds like eos.se and eos in general are linked / endorsed which atm they're not. It would confuse me if I didn't know you were a dev. Waldyrious may have a different opinion tho of course.

Comment: @Tim ah okay that kind of neutral. That makes sense. I'll be more careful not to use 1st person statements

Comment: @DanielForé it's not just direct communication, it's more about your attitude. The general tone of your messages sometimes tends a bit to the sarcastic, other times your directness may come off as blunt ([example](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/2d7114/elementary_os_freya_beta_1_available_for/cjnop12?context=1)). But apart from personal attacks (justified or not), I don't think you have to change how you interact with others, especially as one of the leaders of a project so focused in proper design, which needs a consistent vision. I just don't think it's well suited for a moderator :)

Comment: @waldyrious thanks for your feedback! I don't think I've ever personally attacked anyone, so I'm not sure what that is in reference to. I definitely haven't intended to be sarcastic, but I do value concision over lengthy answers

Comment: To give you a concrete example, the edit you made to [my question about the scrollbars](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/269/84) totally changed its meaning. I understand that I misled you with the talk about the floating handle, but I can't help but think that by editing the question as you did, you were either overconfident that you understood what I meant, or felt the lost information (about the scrollbar thickness) wasn't significant. Either way, this kind of boldness is what I mean by your attitude, which again, you shouldn't change, but IMHO a moderator needs to be more cautious,

Comment: Heheh online communication is hard. I don't think I've seen gratuitous personal attacks from you either, I meant things like this: ["ITT: Lots of FUD; 0 logic."](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/28w45u/audacious_going_back_to_gtk2_starting_with/cifuvyb), again from reddit and which are (valid or not) negative assessments of other commenters. In fact, I think that the fact they allow sorting one's comments by most controversial is quite useful (well, ascending by votes perhaps would be more) for this sort of analysis. There are probably patterns to be found there :)

Comment: @waldyrious Ah I'm sorry I misunderstood. In this case, the proposed answer would not work if you had ayatana scrollbars installed. So I intended to confirm that with my comment (which you confirmed). It was only at that point I made the edit and the answer which gives you the normal scrollbars which are both thicker and do not have the overlay. The intention of the edit was to assist other users in finding this answer if they had the same question (how to get rid of ayatana scrollbars). If you never had the ayatana scrollbars, the question should have [tag:luna] removed to prevent confusion

Comment: @waldyrious However your comments seem to indicate that you are on Luna, which means that mentioning ayatana scrollbars is indeed important since the answer *will not work* while you have them installed and indeed references CSS files that don't exist for you.

Comment: @DanielForé I hate to pollute this thread with more off-topic stuff, but just to respond, indeed I applied both solutions and didn't realize the other depended on yours to work (I tried yours first). We should probably clean up that question and its answers to make these nuances clear to everyone. I'll talk to you on chat (but later; my time today is up :P) to make sure I understand everything and then propose edits / change accepted answers as appropriate.

Comment: @waldyrious that sounds like a plan! Thanks :)

Comment: @DanielForé I finally got to experiment thoroughly in a clean system and fix the accepted answer in the scrollbar question. Please take a look and fix any incorrections. I'm also thinking of deleting the comments on that answer since they're now irrelevant. Do you agree?

Answer (score 6):

### [waldyrious](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/84/waldyrious)

### [Activity](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/84/waldyrious?tab=activity)

### [Meta](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/users/84/waldyrious?tab=activity)

[flair http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/98363.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/98363/waldyrious)

waldyrious is a keen elementary OS user. He has made quality contributions on the site, in the form of posts but also of comments, reviews, etc. His comments and chat activity reflects a willingness to discuss issues and a propensity to remain level-headed which are qualities that make a good moderator.

---

After careful consideration, I decided to **tentatively decline** the nomination. I certainly believe I could help the site as a moderator (over the last few years, I've helped moderate several online communities, from wikipedias to subreddits to mailing lists). However, at the moment I simply don't have the availability to be around as often as I assume is expected from a community moderator. I really want to see this SE site succeed, but until I finish my PhD, which might still take me a few months, I can't guarantee consistent and frequent dedication to moderation duties.

**That said**, if there isn't a limit on the number of moderators, I'd be happy to assist now and then as time permits. I believe any help would be a net positive, and I know when to defer to others if I feel that a limited presence may have reduced my knowledge and judgment of a specific issue.

Regardless of the community's decision, I appreciate the nomination and kind words :)

Comment: was there a reason for the rollback? It looks much better if they are all in the same style - and it's also easier to edit again if you use the citation style link. Did I change something or did you just not want it edited? It is CW as well...

Comment: @Tim Why did you edit solely to remove the activity link? It's useful.

Comment: Sorry, I also moved it to be multiple lines and made the links citation.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm away for the weekend, will properly react on Monday. Thanks @Gilles for the nomination and the vote of confidence :)

Answer (score -4):

### [Tim](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/3/tim)

### [Meta](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3/tim)

[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3203697.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/3203697/tim)

- **Third** user to join this site; taking into account that the first user is an employee, then **second** user.
- [Has *tons* of rep](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), much more then all the preceding users, **first** user by the reputation rank.

  > [image]
- **Most** active participator, both on the [main](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation) and on [meta](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation).
- **Most** active [voter](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all).
- **Most** active [editor](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all), having made a shocking number of edits.
- Has more posts than anyone.

---

#### I decline, for a number of reasons. I don't feel capable to support this site in the way it would need as I don't have experience moderating, and this site will be different to the others I participate in.

Comment: Eh, @Tim. Not good... I had hopes... You'd make a good mod, seriously. Consider maybe?